# Exclude ".txt" files

Tags: python, regex

I want to exclude ".txt" files of a directory with a regex (and only regex). But this code doesn't work and I don't understand why.
I have this list :

```
['/var/tmp/COMMUN/4.1.0_41/Apache',
 '/var/tmp/COMMUN/4.1.0_41/META-INF', 
 '/var/tmp/COMMUN/4.1.0_41/RewriteRules',
 '/var/tmp/COMMUN/4.1.0_41/Robots', 
 '/var/tmp/COMMUN/4.1.0_41/smokeTest',
 '/var/tmp/COMMUN/4.1.0_41/tutu.txt']
```

And I'm trying this code

```
# list_dit is a personal function
list_dir(toto, filter_function=lambda x: re.match("^.*(?!txt)$", x))
```

Anyone look what is wrong ?

Comment: the `^` at the beginning of your regex is superfluous as you're using re.match which only matches the beginning of the string. If you had used re.search it would matter.

Comment: Note that you would want to match the full extension `.txt` instead of files not ending with `txt`: you want `my_txt` to match.

Comment: Also, I see that you have accepted no answers to any of your questions, if you want to continue to receive answers to your questions you should accept some answers.

Comment: wich, this is the _only_ question the OP has asked that actually _has_ answers? Seems a bit soon to be saying that.

Comment: Have you considered `glob.glob()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually `.*` are greedy matches, they will match as much as they can with the following still matching. As an empty string is an okay match for `(?!txt)` the `.*` will simply match the whole string, meaning that this regular expression will match each and every string.

Simply matching for `.*\.txt$` and negating the re.match would work.

By the way, you should use a compiled regex instead of re.match, now the regex could be compiled for each and every file in your directory. If you use a compiled regex it will only be compiled once. The compiled regex may be cached by the re module, which in this case will likely be the case as there are no other regex calls in between the re.match calls. However it would, in my opinion, be more "correct" if you compile the regex yourself, that way you are sure that it is only compiled once. Thanks to EOL for the heads up on the caching.

Comment: @wich: Your comment about the pre-compilation must be qualified: the more recent patterns are *not* recompiled (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents). So, unless an additional speedup is really needed, there is no need to compile the regex first, as this is already partially optimized by the `re` module.

Comment: Another point is that `not re.search('\.txt',…)$` is a simpler solution.

Comment: @EOL ah, I did not know that about the caching in the module, that is good to know, though it will of course add at least a string compare. In general though I think a compiled version will be better despite the caching, you never know how the code will develop in the future, so I think it's better to "do the right thing" (tm) I kept `match` to stay close to the OP's problem statement, and I don't think it matters from a performance point of view, at least not conceptually, but yes in the same "do the right thing" train of thought `search` would be better.

Comment: @wich: Yeah, I saw that you mentioned `search()` in a comment. I just want to open the answer a little. Note that the regex string is not recreated, it's a constant, so there is no string comparison upon calling `re.search()`, only a very fast pointer comparison. This can be seen with `dis.dis()`, so it's not too bad. We have a different idea of what the "right thing" is, here: you give priority to execution speed and I give priority to a simpler code (which is automatically quite optimized by the `re` module). :)

Answer (score 5):

The reason why `^.*(?!txt)$` doesn't work is because you're using a negative lookahead, but, due to both the greedy nature of `.*` and the anchor `$` you are at the end of the string, and thus **there is nothing ahead** at that point, (so there is nothing for it to fail on).

What you're trying to do can be achieved with a negative lookbehind, which works backwards, and looks like `(^.*(?<!txt)$)`

It should be noted that whilst the lookbehind works here, Python only allows fixed length strings for it (lookahead doesn't have this constraint).
Other regex implementations allow limited length lookbehinds (i.e. can't use `.*` but can do `.{0,10}`), whilst others (including JavaScript), don't support lookbehind at all.

(If you needed this for a non-fixed match or in a JS environment, wich's suggestion of `.*txt$` then negating the result can solve that.)

For more information on both lookahead and lookbehind, take a look at this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

*(Of course, you should ideally be using `\.txt` in the regex to ensure it's the full extension, and the most efficient solution is likely the already suggested [x.endswith('.txt')](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method.)*

Answer (score 3):

How about a simpler solution?

```
x.endswith(".txt")
```

If you *must* use regeex:

```
not re.search("\\.txt$", x)
```

- `not` *not* match
- `\\.` a single dot `.`
- `txt`
- `$` end of input

Comment: What is `!` in python?

Comment: Yes, it works. But I don't need solution. I need to understand why it doesn't work for my mind :)

Comment: @Tichodroma probably you have had too much java recently :)

Comment: @Tichodroma Since when?

Comment: If your regex is only going to match the suffix of the filename you need to use re.search instead of re.match

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone look what is wrong ?

`^` matches the start of the string, then `.*` matches every single character in the input string, now comes `(?!txt)` and there is nothing left in the input string at this point but the end-of-string so it passes every time, after that `$` matches end-of-string.

You can fix this with a much simpler regular expression like this:

```
list_dir(toto, filter_function=lambda x: not re.search(r"\.txt$", x))
```

Comment: You probably mean `re.search`, not `re.find`

Comment: @wich Thank you, I don't work with Python, I will fix this right ahead.